# Error:(52, 14) error: cannot find symbol method onPreExecute() on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm trying out a login tutorial ([Create an Android login system using MySQL](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-android-user-login-system-using-mysql/31512)) on Android Studio 3.0. I ran into these errors:

- [`import android.os.AsyncTask;` (Click here to see the error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XL0m.jpg)

When I hover on it, it says:

> Unused import statement

- [`onPreExecute()` (Click here to see the error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W7FH.jpg)

The message shows:

> Error:(52, 14) error: cannot find symbol method onPreExecute()

Can anybody help me out? I'm new to this. I'm sorry if the question is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I feeling your question unclearly, if you have error: **cannot find symbol method onPreExecute()** so right click Source in your Asyntask class -> `Override --> Implement method` and figure out `onPreExecute()` method.

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear question. I have edited the post and added some images for references. What did you meant by 'Source' in 'AsyncTask class'? I couldn't find any 'Source' in the class.When I opened the class, on top of it shows, **Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8)** and **Sources for 'Android API 26 Platform' not found.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand your problem, when you create class extend `Asyntask`, you should Override three methods (`onPreExecute`, `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`). In order to Override methods, any position mouse in class extend `Asyntask` you right click and choise `Generate...`(or shortKey: Alt + Insert) --> `Override Methods` --> choise `onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute`). See all step with images below:

[image: choise methods for asyntask]

[image: finish asyntask]

finish Override for Asyntask.

Comment: The current `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` and `doInBackground()` methods are in `public class login extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener`. What did I need to do?

Comment: Just use onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(), doInbackground() inner class extends Asyntask. If you handle feature login who can send username and password to Asyntask handle, and return result success or fail to onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

Try Rebuild the project or restart android studio. Android Studio sometimes gives these kinds of issues